# form(method='get') works for node.js, but status: pending in dev-tools

Tags: html, node.js, pug

I am making a webpage that uses forms to submit user votes to a mongo database using node. While the code below sucessfully modifies the db, it causes a pending status operation in chrome dev-tools. This prevents all js from running, and after a few minutes the browser redirects to (the non-existant) /v/foo. This problem also occurs when using 'post' rather than 'get' as the method.

**index.jade:**

```
form(method= 'get', action= '/v/foo')
  button.vote(type= 'submit')
```

**app.js:** `app.get('/v/:postID', home.vote);`

**home.js:**

```
exports.vote = function(req, res){
  // gets postID from the URL
  postID = req.params.postID;
  // gets logged-in user
  user = req.session.username;
  // sends postID, retrieves a post with ID postID
  postdb.findPost(postID, function(post){
  // readPost(postID, function(post){
    // increments the 'votes' property of the comment by 1
    titles.update({postID: postID}, {$inc: {ups: 1}}, function(err){
      if (err) throw err;
    });

    // code that calculates current post level and progress goes here (works fine)

    // updates level and level progress
    titles.update({postID: postID}, {$set: {level: level, lvlProg: lvlProg}}, function(err){
      if (err) throw err;
    });

    accounts.update({username: user}, {$push: {votedPosts: postID}}, function(err){
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log('recorded')
    });

  });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code doesn't send a response, so the browser gets confused. ;)

Try `res.send(200);` if everything succeeds.

The HTTP form still expects its request to be closed cleanly and node will happily hold onto that connection indefinitely, if you don't `end` it with `res.send()`.